# android 2.2 sms receiver wont work

Tags: android, sms

guys. I am new to android and i am using android 2.2 for some sms_receive thing: when an sms received, just a notification. but it won't work...  Nothing happens when sms received, seems like the receiver has not been registered.
help!

Code for `androidmanifest.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.happyto.tracker"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".Track">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name=".SMSReceiver" android:enabled="true">
        <intent_filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
        </intent_filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

</manifest>
```

my receiver class : `SMSReceiver.java`:

```
package com.happyto.tracker;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;

import android.content.Context;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.telephony.SmsMessage;

import android.widget.Toast;
import android.util.Log;

public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String smsReceived = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
        Log.e("tracker", intent.getAction());
        if (intent.getAction().equals(smsReceived)) {
            // ---get the SMS message passed in---
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
            String str = "";
            if (bundle != null) {
                // ---retrieve the SMS message received---
                Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
                    msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                    str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                    str += " :";
                    str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                    str += "\n";
                }
                // ---display the new SMS message---
                Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452808/sending-and-receiving-mms-in-android

Answer (score 2):

```
 private static final String TAG = "smsfwd";
    private static final String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";

    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    private int SIMPLE_NOTFICATION_ID;
    String str="";
    String SMS_MIME_TYPE = "vnd.android-dir/mms-sms";

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent defineIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);                

        defineIntent.setType(SMS_MIME_TYPE);
        Log.i(TAG, "Intent recieved: " + intent.getAction());
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if (intent.getAction().equals(SMS_RECEIVED)) {
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            if (bundle != null) {
                Object[] pdus = (Object[])bundle.get("pdus");
                final SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];

                for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
                    messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);

                    str += "SMS from" + messages[i].getOriginatingAddress();                     
                    str += ":";
                    str += messages[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                    str += "\n";    
                }
                Log.i(TAG, "Message recieved: " + messages[0].getMessageBody());
                if (messages.length > -1) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Message recieved: " + messages[0].getMessageBody());
                    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    Notification notifyDetails = new Notification(R.drawable.msg,"message received",System.currentTimeMillis());
                    //PendingIntent myIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW), 0);
                      PendingIntent myIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0 , defineIntent, 0);

                    notifyDetails.setLatestEventInfo(context, str, "", myIntent); 
                    notifyDetails.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
                    notifyDetails.flags = Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
                    mNotificationManager.notify(SIMPLE_NOTFICATION_ID, notifyDetails);
              }
            }
         }
       }
```

and manifest file like this..

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.infostretch.broadcastex"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">


    <receiver android:name="broadcastex" android:label="@string/app_name"><intent-filter><action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"></action>
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
</application>



<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

I am running this in android 2.2 working for me make sure you add permission and receiver in android manifest